# System.out hyperlink?

Tags: java, hyperlink

So if i call

```
public void throwException throws Exception {     
  throw new Exception("foo") ; 
}
```

the output will look something like this:

```
java.lang.Exception: foo
      at SomeClass.throwException(SomeClass.java:5) 
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
      ...
```

now if i click on `(SomeClass.java:5)`, the IDE jumps to the 5-th line in SomeClass.java.

Is it possible to manually generate those hyperlinks, when using System.out or throwing an Exception? I already tried manipulating an Exception by changing a StackTraceElement, but it seems to work only with valid Java classes.

I'm working on a project, where i have to parse a uniquely defined file and would like to print hyperlinks, which would directly lead to the file, instead of the parse-method where a problem occurred.

Comment: Java does not provide those hyperlinks, your IDE does that by parsing the output.

Comment: But it's an old norm that a lot of text editors implement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If you have a class named MyClass and you want the IDE to provide a link to line 10 of that class, you can do the following:

```
System.out.println("(MyClass.java:10)");
```

Note: This post specifically refers to Eclipse IDE, it might hold true for others as well.

EDIT: I just came across this post, might be worth a look: [Eclipse Console - what are the rules that make stack traces clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232925/eclipse-console-what-are-the-rules-that-make-stack-traces-clickable)

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355286/how-to-format-output-to-console-to-generate-automatic-navigation-hyperlink-fro -- hopefully this one is more helpful :)

Comment: well thats something, but still i'm not able to link to other files than Java classes :(

Comment: found something [here](http://jimbarritt.com/non-random/2010/05/16/link-from-log-console-output-to-a-line-of-code-in-intellij/), but it still wont work with normal files...