# Source code link in log in NetBeans IDE / Java

Tags: java, logging, netbeans

When my program prints stack trace in NetBeans IDE, for example this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Not implemented yet
    at App.App.main(App.java:202)
```

The "App.java:202" part is a link. When I click it, it directs me to the file and line.

I would like to do this in my own logs. Just printing it doesn't work for me.

My not functional log line example:

```
2015/06/01 10:27:19.197 (DbConnection.java:119) ExecuteQuery  ....
```

Solution:

```
StackTraceElement s = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1];
System.out.printf("%s.%s(%s:%s)%n", s.getClassName(), s.getMethodName(),s.getFileName(), s.getLineNumber());
```

New problem:

If I print this:

```
App.App.RunTests(App.java:128)  th_id:1,main   WARN  null Database.DbValuesCache.run(DbValuesCache.java:153) ....
```

.. only the first link works.

What now?

Comment: Have you tried -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232925/eclipse-console-what-are-the-rules-that-make-stack-traces-clickable