# Parse console output to make error messages link to source code (similar to quickfix lists in vim)

Tags: eclipse, parsing, logging, console, watch

In VIM, users can define an errorformat and use it to parse messages from an external tool (e.g. grep, lint, compiler etc.).

In Eclipse, the output of external tools is displayed in the console. Does Eclipse provide a feature similar to VIM's errorformat + quickfix/location lists that allow users to simply parse those messages and turn it into some sort of clickable list or to parse the messages and turn references to source code into hyperlinks? What is the best way to do this in Eclipse?

Edit: Is it possible to achieve this without having to write a plugin. If not, has nobody yet written such a generic plugin? It is somehow hard to imagine that nobody has yet come up with an solution for this.

Edit2: If this is not possible easily in eclipse, is there a tool that allows watching the output of a command (or logs in general) and that turns filenames + line numbers into hyperlinks that can be opened with a user-configurable editor?

Comment: You would have to write an Eclipse plugin to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following "[Eclipse console: detect warning and error patterns and make them clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906261/eclipse-console-detect-warning-and-error-patterns-and-make-them-clickable)", I realized I can use "Grep Console" to achieve this. Excellent plugin. For whatever reason I previously thought it can only be used to color output.